# D3 show tooltip on mouse over with a timeout

Tags: d3.js, mouseevent, settimeout, transition, mouseenter

I want to add tooltips to the barchar's rects every time the mouse enters a rect and the mouse is over the rect after some milliseconds. I also want to remove them when the mouse leaves any rect.

I tried it binding it with d3 events and using setTimeout/clearTimeout.

It seems to work **except when you move the mouse quickly through different bars while the line of the tooltip is transitioning,**

**The problem** in this cases **is** that the **tooltip is moved from bar to bar** that the mouse enters/leaves 
**with disregard of the timeout.** The text of the tooltip does seem to do some weird things.

Let me show you how the tooltip appears before the timeout:

[image: gif showing the problem]

[DEMO and FULL CODE at CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/40detectives/pen/ZOeYxp/)

Code for binding the functions that paints the tooltips:

```
... 
var bar = svg.select(".bars")
            .selectAll(".barchart-group")
            .data(data);
... 
var come = bar.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .style("stroke", undefined)
            .style("fill", "hsla(34, 82%, 48%, 0.79)");
... 
        //bind events to new bars
        come.on("mouseover", delayTooltip)
            .on("mouseout", removeBarTooltip);
...
```

Code of the tootlip related functions:

```
function delayTooltip(d, i) {
  // this here is every rect of the bar chart
    this.hoverTimeout = window.setTimeout(addBarTooltip.bind(this), 1000, d, i);
}

function addBarTooltip(d, i) {
  // **** PROBLEM **** 
  // this executes whithout waiting the set timeout
    var firstAnims = 500;
    var thisbar = d3.select(this);
    var tooltip = d3.select(this.parentNode);
    var gRoot = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode);
    //Lets define some points of interest
    var p0 = [+thisbar.attr("x") + (barWidth - 1) / 2, +thisbar.attr("y")];
    var p1 = [p0[0], +p0[1] - 9];
    var p2 = [p0[0], +p0[1] - 13];
    //relevant points to draw tooltips
    var line = gRoot.select(".linePointers");
    var text = gRoot.select(".textHelpers");
    line.append("polyline")
        .style("stroke-dasharray", "2,1")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .attr("points", [p0, p0])
        .transition("line-Y-axis")
        .duration(firstAnims)
        .attrTween("points", function(d, i, a) {
            return d3.interpolate([p0, p0], [p0, p1]);
        });

    text.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".2em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", p2[0])
        .attr("y", p1[1])
        .text(d.value)
        .style("font-size", ".85em")
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .transition("text-Y-axis")
        .delay(firstAnims)
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .attr("y", p2[1]);

}

function removeBarTooltip() {
    window.clearTimeout(this.hoverTimeout);
    var firstAnims = 200;
    var thisbar = d3.select(this);
    var tooltip = d3.select(this.parentNode);
    var gRoot = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode);
    //relevant points to draw tooltips
    var p0 = [+thisbar.attr("x") + (barWidth - 1) / 2, +thisbar.attr("y")];
    var p1 = [p0[0], +p0[1] - 9];
    var p2 = [p0[0], +p0[1] - 13];
    //Lets make a group for each part of our tooltip
    var line = gRoot.select(".linePointers")
        .selectAll("polyline");
    var text = gRoot.select(".textHelpers")
        .selectAll("text");

    line.transition("line-Y-axis")
        .duration(firstAnims)
        .attrTween("points", function(d, i, a) {
            return d3.interpolate([p0, p1], [p0, p0]);
        })
        .remove();

    text.style("opacity", 0.7)
        .transition("text-Y-axis")
        .delay(firstAnims)
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .attr("dy", p0[1] - p2[1])
        .remove();
}
```

I prefer avoid adding any other libraries if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `removeBarTooltip()`. Let's look first at this two lines where i defined the points for a tootlip line:

```
var p0 = [+thisbar.attr("x") + (barWidth - 1) / 2, +thisbar.attr("y")];
var p1 = [p0[0], +p0[1] - 9];
```

later in this function I was doing:

```
[...]
line.transition("line-Y-axis")
    .duration(firstAnims)
    .attrTween("points", function(d, i, a) {
        return d3.interpolate([p0, p1], [p0, p0]);
    })
    .remove();
```

So what was happening is that the tootlip line was moving from bar to bar due to `var p0` value depending on the bar the mouse is over.

To solve this I changed the line transition with attrTween to:

```
line.transition("line-Y-axis")
    .duration(firstAnims)
    .attrTween("points", function(d, i, a) {
        var p0current = a.split(",");
        var p1current = p0current.splice(2);
        return d3.interpolate([p0current, p1current], [p0current, p0current]);
    })
    .remove();
```

Where it takes the actual value of the points property with argument `a` and interpolates the actual movemevent based only on it.

[DEMO and FULL code at CODEPEN.](http://codepen.io/40detectives/pen/LRVkrZ)

Answer (score -1):

Try foxToolTip.js

Has options for delay and transition duration for both hover and mouseout

https://github.com/MichaelRFox/foxToolTip.js

Check out my bl.ock at: http://bl.ocks.org/MichaelRFox/59cdc1c3478fb0362448cf87fdab30d0

Uses a 0.5 second delay to show the tooltip upon hover over the text elements

Comment: I'd like to avoid adding more libs to my project as much as i can. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your bl.ock does not seem to work for me (since the day you posted) correctly, can you check it out @m-fox, please?